# Modules which are isomorphic to their tensor product.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

Suppose that we have a commutative ring $R$. I am interested in finding the (finitely generated and projective, if you want) $R$-modules $M,$ such that $M\cong M\otimes_R M$ as $R$-modules.
 I know that it is true for $M=R$ or when $M$ is generated by a finite  set of orthogonal  idempotents.

I want to know if whether or not those are all the modules which that property. Thanks.

Comment: What are "orthogonal idempotents" in a module?

Comment: @xyzzyz: probably he means M ≤ R is a direct summand of R. Certain S1 and S2 work in S1 × S2.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: I was guessing he means that M is isomorphic to a product of some $R/I$ for $I \triangleleft R$.

Comment: @xyzzyz When i said that $M$ is generated by a finite set of ortogonal idempotents, i meant that $M=\sum_{i\in I}Re_i,$ where $\{e_i\}\subseteq R$ is a set of orthogonal idempotents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some examples:

- Localizations or quotients of $R$.
- More generally any [epimorphism of commutative rings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like) with domain $R$.
- Free $R$-modules of infinite rank.
- $R \oplus \bigoplus_{i \in I} N$ for any $R$-module $N$ with $N \otimes N = 0$.

The finitely generated examples can be classified:

**Claim**: When $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module with $M \otimes M \cong M$, then $M$ is cyclic, i.e. $M \cong R/I$ for some ideal $I \subseteq R$.

Proof: We may base change to $R/\mathrm{Ann}(M)$ and therefore assume that $\mathrm{Ann}(M)=0$. Then we have to show $M \cong R$. Since $M$ is finitely generated, we have $\mathrm{supp}(M)=V(\mathrm{Ann}(M))=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$. For every $\mathfrak{p} \in \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ therefore $M \otimes \kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ is $1$-dimensional and $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is generated by a single element (Nakayama). Since $\mathrm{Ann}(M_{\mathfrak{p}})=0$, this implies that $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is free of rank $1$. Hence $M$ is locally free of rank $1$, hence invertible, and $M \otimes M \cong M$ implies $M \cong R$. $\square$

Of course, $R$ is the only finitely generated projective example (when $R$ is a domain).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, when you say "We may base change to R/{\rm Ann}(M)" do you mean that $M\otimes_R M\cong M$ is equivalent to $M\otimes_{R/{\rm Ann}(M)}M\cong M$?.

Comment: @HectorPinedo: what you say is true and works. this is basically the point behind his first and second bullet points. If $M,N$ are $S$ modules and $f:R\to S$ is epic, then $M\otimes_R N \cong M \otimes_S N$ as $S$-modules.

Comment: @JackSchmidt, So for the general case. $M$ is a faithful $R/{\rm Ann}(M)$-module and $M\cong R/{\rm Ann}(M),$ am i right?.

In this case the ideal mentioned by Martin in its  claim is exactly ${\rm Ann}(M).$

Comment: @HectorPinedo: yes, exactly. In other words, Ann(R/I)=I.